# PHP regex match something not starting with words like "admin", "login"... and so on?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've searched a lot but I've found **many complicated examples**, too hard to understand for me. Anyways I'm trying to write down a regular expression that should honor:

```
/foo     // should match
/foo/bar // should match

/login     // shouldn't match
/admin     // shouldn't match
/admin/foo // shouldn't match
/files     // shouldn't match
```

I've tried with a simple one, just with one word: `#^(\/)([^admin])#` that is starting with `/` and followed by something not starting with the word `admin`. It's working with `/foo/bar` but fails with `/a/foo` because it's starting with `a`, I suppose.

How can negate an entire set of words (`admin` or `files` or `login`)?

Comment: What you are looking for is called "zero-width assertions" or "lookahead" and "lookbehind". http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I can't, the regex is for Symfony route matcher, accepting only regular expressions.

Comment: @Polmonino You should edit that info into to the question above.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$pattern = '#^(\/)((?!admin|login).)*$#';
```

or

```
$pattern = '#^(/)((?!admin|login).)(/(.)+)*#';
$array = array(
'/foo',     // should match
'/foo/bar', // should match

'/login',     // shouldn't match
'/admin',     // shouldn't match
'/admin/foo', // shouldn't match
'/files'     // shouldn't match
);

foreach($array as $test){
 if(preg_match($pattern, $test)) echo "Matched :".$test."<br>";
 else echo "Not Matched:".$test."<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
Matched :/foo
Matched :/foo/bar
Not Matched:/login
Not Matched:/admin
Not Matched:/admin/foo
Matched :/files
```

Comment: Why you added the end of the string?

Comment: Doesn’t match `/not-admin` either.

Comment: @Polmonino: I removed but the dot matches all after first group

Comment: @Gumbo: OP asked for `/admin` and `/login`

Comment: @Akam So it should match `/no-admin`, right?

Comment: @Akam And now after your change it does match both `/admin` and `/login`.

Comment: @Akam You don’t really know regex, do you? Use `^/(?!(admin|login|files)($|/))` instead.

Comment: @Gumbo: But I know how to talk with people! rep is nothing! you have to teach your self how to deal with people in public comminity!!!

Comment: @Gumbo: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/zpe-1ex here is your pattern! haha

Comment: @Akam So what? I don’t see anything wrong there.

Comment: haha I knew, there is nothing wrong with mine also

Comment: so which pattern is correct?